# Creating Folder in SharePoint in Windows Form Application using VB

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, directory

I am working on a Windows Form application where i need to create a folder in a SharePoint Directory, then save an excel file in that folder.

The code i am using to currently save my excel file in the sharepoint directory works as inteded.

```
        Dim xlsApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim xlsWB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        xlsApp.Visible = True
        xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\Records\1234_TEST.xls")
        xlsWB.SaveAs("//oil.Test.com/oil452-6603/TEST_FOLDER/1234_TEST.xls")
```

The problem i am having is i need to create a Folder in the SharePoint directory inside say "TEST_FOLDER" to actually put the excel file into.  Im not going to be running this on the same computer as the sharepoint server, and i havent been able to figure a way to create a folder inside the sharepoint via code.

Adding the Folder via sharepoint manually is not an option because i need to create alot of these extra folders / excel files per folder.

Any help on what i need to do to be able to Create a folder so i can save my excel file into would be greatly appreciated.  Thank You

Comment: Considered using a connector like Camelot .NET Connector?

Comment: I dont think the need for the extra software installed on the computer that will be running this application will be acceptable for the solution.  More looking for a version that can be run while not on the SharePoint server aswell as something that doesent need special software downloaded for the use of the application.

Comment: Well, then you must setup an API that your application integrates towards. This API is certainly best placed on or near the SharePoint server. The API itself can communicate with SharePoint through the ClientContext API or Camelot .NET Connector.

Comment: So there is no way to add a folder in some way i saved my excel file?  I was hoping there was some way around communicating with the SharePoint through some connection.

Comment: There are a few api's. Remember that SharePoint is a heavy duty system and not a fileserver. Anything you see in SharePoint is stored in a database and not the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SharePoint web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29) to do what you require, you'll want to use the [Lists web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28v=office.12%29). See [this blog post](http://sridharu.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/createdelete-folers-using-listsasmx-web.html) for an example of creating a folder (I haven't tested it but it looks good).